# How to create image based on dropdownlist selected value?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, canvas, drop-down-menu

I have created a button with allow me to create image on canvas for drag and drop canvas.

```
 <button type="button" class="btn-one" onclick="addimage3();">Board</button>
function addimage3(){
var img2 = document.createElement("img");
img2.src = "object3.png";
img2.height = 20;
img2.width = 400;

var class_name = "foo";
img2.setAttribute("class", class_name);

document.getElementById("pc").appendChild(img2);
 $(img2).draggable();
}
```

I know that I need to create many button in order to let user able to create many image in canvas for drag and drop, Is that possible to make them into dropdownlist and make it will create the image based on what user choose in the list?

Comment: You've tagged this question `asp.net`, yet there is no mention of asp.net in the question. Please add more relevant code or remove the tag.

Answer (score 0):

You want to grab the value of the drop-down so you can figure out which image type the user selected. Using a switch statement, you can set the image attributes based on which type they picked.

```js
function addImage() {
  var type = document.querySelector("#imgtype").value;
  var imgElem = document.createElement("img");
  
  switch (type) {
    case "img1":
      imgElem.src= "https://images.pexels.com/photos/736230/pexels-photo-736230.jpeg";
      break;
      
    case "img2":
      imgElem.src= "https://www.carmax.com/cars/images/type-icons/sedans.svg";
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("pc").appendChild(imgElem);
}

// Make it onChange of the select
document.querySelector('#imgtype').addEventListener('change', (e) => { addImage(); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="imgtype">
  <option value="img1" selected>Flower</option>
  <option value="img2">Car</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onClick="addImage()">Add Image</button>
<div id="pc"></div>
```

Comment: Is that possible to call function when user select a option in dropdownlist which does not need a button to trigger the function? Use onchange() ?

Comment: @Roxas Sure, I added a line that does that

Comment: I tried the code, but the function wont work and call when me select any option in dropdownlist....

Comment: Can you update the question with your new code? Including the html of your dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Create a `<select>` element with as many options as you have images. Every option `value` attribute will hold the `src` of the image. Now everytime listen for the `change` event on the `<select>` element to get the URL of the currently selected image.

Then when you got the URL, create a new image and set the `src` property to the selected URL. From here append the image to the desired element and your image has been chosen.

Example below:

```js
// Select the select field and the image container.
const select = document.getElementById('select-image');
const imgContainer = document.getElementById('image-container');

select.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  const value = event.target.value; // Get the value of the selected option.
  const image = new Image();        // Create new image.
  image.src = value;                // Set value to image.
  imgContainer.innerHTML = '';      // Empty container.
  imgContainer.appendChild(image);  // Add image to container.
});
```

```html
<select id="select-image" name="image">
  <option hidden value="">Choose image</option>
  <option value="https://www.placecage.com/640/360">Image 1</option>
  <option value="https://placebeard.it/640x360">Image 2</option>
  <option value="https://baconmockup.com/640/360">Image 3</option>
</select>

<div id="image-container">

</div>
```